# Undefined cran_mirror when building conda packages

Tags: r, conda

I am trying to build an R package in conda using skeleton. After preparing the environment with the required packages, I execute the following commands

```
$ conda skeleton cran arules
$ conda build r-arules
```

The recipe files are generated and everything seems OK, but the build command results into the following error:

```
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for r-arules
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for r-arules
Undefined Jinja2 variables remain (['cran_mirror', 'cran_mirror']). 
Please enable source downloading and try again.
```

I've been reading the documentation and searching the Web for a solution to this problem, without success, and I do not know what else to do. ¿Any ideas?

**Notes**: I've started following this tutorial: http://ihrke.github.io/conda.html but afterwards I have also checked the official [conda documentation on building packages](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/index.html) and other related docs. I have updated conda (= 4.5.2), as well as conda-build ( = 3.10.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out how to solve my issue in two different ways:

The most straight solution is to specify a cran url using **--cran-url** option when creating the recipse, as follows:

`$ conda skeleton cran arules --cran-url  https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01/`

Another solution is to create a *conda-build* config file, using **yaml**. Inside that file we specify the cran mirror, for example:

> cran_mirror: https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-01-01/

And then, we should use option **-m** when creating the recipe

`$ conda skeleton cran arules -m path/to/conda_build_config.yam`

PD: It seems there will be a default cran mirror in the next release of *conda-build*, according to comments in this [pull request](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/pull/2836)